# appmaker developing environment drops window in chrome

Tags: google-app-maker

I always go to my google drive to click the appmaker project which I want to edit. However, when launching it, appmaker will drop the window automatically right after it shows the main edit panel. Therefore, I cannot edit any things in my project.
**If I use an incognito window to edit my project, everything is fine.** Fortunately, I do not have this problem for the finished product I released to domain users. Please help me with this issue. How should I do to let appmaker execute properly under a normal window of chrome?

Comment: Perhaps you are signed into more than one google account in the same chrome profile. I'd recommend not do that if that is the case.

Comment: Thank you Morfinismo for your help. Maybe I should try to reinstall my chrome.